# Please help me find out what's wrong with this .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./rewrite.php?p=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]   
</IfModule>
```

rewrite.php

```
<?php 
print_R($_GET);die;
?>
```

This works properly on my local comp and on many other servers. But on a godaddy server there is an issue.
URL like this gets successfully processed

```
site.com/search/action/browse
Array ( [p] => search/action/browse )
```

But this URL has a problem

```
site.com/index/country/United-States
Array ( [p] => missing.html )
```

There is no index/ directory in the site root. There is an index.php file though. I tried to go through godaddy control panel but didn't find anything related to missing.html. Please let me know your thoughts because I am running out of ideas.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but I think you can use [L,QSA] instead of appending `&%{QUERY_STRING}`

Comment: you could use this guy technique: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/crazy-advanced-mod_rewrite-tutorial.html to get a nice debug of some mod_rewrite variables in the $_SERVER array. May gives you hints on what happended in the rewrite process. Certainly another rewrite rule is applied before yours. Best thing would be altering rewriteLog and rewriteLogLevel to get the trace.

Comment: @Eugene Do you see any difference if you add this line: `Options -MultiViews` ? I don't really think it should work hence just a comment.

Comment: I had the same problem with RewriteRules not working and the "missing.html". LasyOne's suggestion worked - I added Options - MultiViews and everything started to work as expected!

Answer (score 1):

LazyOne: you are a legend: Ive had this issue for months and the wonderful `"Options -MultiViews"` saved me.